# Bidirectional @OneToMany relationship with composite pks using SpringBoot and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, one-to-many

I have an existing parent-child relationship in our application that has become more complex recently because we have added a "type" column to the primary key of both the parent and the child. After this, adding, reading and modifying children works well but removing them is a pain.

Using the advice given in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) by Vlad Mihalcea on @OneToMany relationships and also various examples on the composite keys, I have tried an implementation similar to the following model. However, removing children still doesn't work and I now have a weird error message as a bonus.

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Hibernate 5.1.9.Final.

### The case

A Parent entity has an @EmbeddedId ParentPK with two fields and a `children` collection with `Cascade.ALL` and `orphanRemoval` set to true.

#### Parent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "z_parent")
public class Parent {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ParentPK pk;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_code", referencedColumnName = "code"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_type", referencedColumnName = "type")
    })
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Parent() {
    }

    public Parent(String code, String type) {
        this.pk = new ParentPK(code, type);
    }

    public void addChild(Child child){
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child){
        child.setParent(null);
        children.remove(child);
    }

    //getters and setters, including delegate getters and setters


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Parent)) return false;

        Parent parent = (Parent) o;

        return pk.equals(parent.pk);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return pk.hashCode();
    }

}
```

#### ParentPK

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    public ParentPK() {
    }

    public ParentPK(String code, String type) {
        this.code = code;
        this.type = type;
    }

    //getters and setters    

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ParentPK)) return false;

        ParentPK parentPK = (ParentPK) o;

        if (!getCode().equals(parentPK.getCode())) return false;
        return getType().equals(parentPK.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getCode().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getType().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `Child` entity has its own `code` identifier which, together with the two Strings identifying the parent, form another composite primary key. The relation with Parent is bidirectional, so the Child also has a `parent` field annotated with @ManyToOne.

#### Child

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "z_child")
public class Child {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPk pk = new ChildPk();

    //The two columns of the foreign key are also part of the primary key
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_code", referencedColumnName = "code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_type", referencedColumnName = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Parent parent;

    public Child() {
    }

    public Child(String code, String parentCode, String parentType) {
        this.pk = new ChildPk(code, parentCode, parentType);
    }

    //getters and setters, including delegate getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Child)) return false;

        Child child = (Child) o;

        return pk.equals(child.pk);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return pk.hashCode();
    }    
}
```

#### ChildPK

```
@Embeddable
class ChildPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "parent_code")
    private String parentCode;
    @Column(name = "parent_type")
    private String parentType;

    public ChildPk() {
    }

    public ChildPk(String code, String parentCode, String parentType) {
        this.code = code;
        this.parentCode = parentCode;
        this.parentType = parentType;
    }

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ChildPk)) return false;

        ChildPk childPk = (ChildPk) o;

        if (!getCode().equals(childPk.getCode())) return false;
        if (!getParentCode().equals(childPk.getParentCode())) return false;
        return getParentType().equals(childPk.getParentType());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getCode().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getParentCode().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getParentType().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Since I am using Spring, I have declared a simple CRUD repository for the Parent:

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, ParentPK> {
}
```

### The problem

Let's say that I already have a Parent with two children in the database:

**z_Parent**

"code",   "type"

"Parent", "Adoptive"

**z_child**

"code",   "parent_code",  "parent_type"

"Child1", "Parent",        "Adoptive"

"Child2", "Parent",        "Adoptive"

, and that I have to persist an updated version of the parent, containing only the first child:

```
public Parent mapFromUpperLayer(){
    Parent updatedParent =new Parent("Parent", "Adoptive");

    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    Child child1 = new Child("Child1", updatedParent);
    child1.setParent(updatedParent);
    children.add(child1);

    updatedParent.setChildren(children);

    return updatedParent;
}
```

If I simply save the entity with one child:

```
@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;

@Test
@Commit
public void saveUpdate(){
    Parent updatedParent = mapFromUpperLayer();
    parentRepository.save(updatedParent);
}
```

then I have the following result (I have cleared the log a bit):

```
Hibernate: select parent0_.code as code1_50_1_, parent0_.type as type2_50_1_, children1_.parent_code as parent_c2_49_3_, children1_.parent_type as parent_t3_49_3_, children1_.code as code1_49_3_, children1_.code as code1_49_0_, children1_.parent_code as parent_c2_49_0_, children1_.parent_type as parent_t3_49_0_ from z_parent parent0_ left outer join z_child children1_ on parent0_.code=children1_.parent_code and parent0_.type=children1_.parent_type where parent0_.code=? and parent0_.type=?
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Parent]
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Adoptive]

Hibernate: update z_child set parent_code=null, parent_type=null 
           where parent_code=? and parent_type=? and code=?
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Parent]
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [Adoptive]
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Child2]
TRACE 12412 ---  : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Parent]
 INFO 12412 ---  : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
 WARN 12412 ---  : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22023
ERROR 12412 ---  : L'indice de la colonne est hors limite : 4, nombre de colonnes : 3.
```

There are two problems here. Hibernate correctly identifies that *Child2* is to be removed from the parent generates an update rather than a delete query. I used a bidirectional relationship exactly in order to avoid this but it appears I have not understood completely how it works. And, of course, the update it generates contains four parameters for three columns ("Parent" appears twice), which is bizarre.

### What I have already tried

First, I have retrieved the entity from the database, removed both it's children and set their parent to *null* (`removeChild` method) and added the new list also taking care to set every time the parent to the instance I was going to save (`addChild` method).

```
@Test
@Commit
public void saveUpdate2(){
    Parent updatedParent = mapFromUpperLayer();

    Parent persistedParent = parentRepository.findOne(new ParentPK(updatedParent.getCode(), updatedParent.getType()));

    //remove all the children and add the new collection, both one by one
    (new ArrayList<>(persistedParent.getChildren()))
            .forEach(child -> persistedParent.removeChild(child));

    updatedParent.getChildren().forEach(child -> persistedParent.addChild(child));

    parentRepository.save(persistedParent);
}
```

Secondly I have tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791726/hibernate-onetomany-with-mismatched-composite-primary-keys), that is I have declared the @ManyToOne part of the relationship directly inside ChildPK:

```
@Embeddable
class ChildPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_code", referencedColumnName = "code"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_type", referencedColumnName = "type")
    })
    private Parent parent;

    public ChildPk() {
    }

    public ChildPk(String code, Parent parent) {
        this.code = code;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    ....
```

In both cases I get the same generated queries and the same error.

### The questions

1. How can I structure my Parent - Child relationship so that Hibernate will be able to delete the removed children when I save the new version of the parent? Ideally I would like to not change the structure of the database too much - a join table, for example, would be rather time-consuming to implement.
2. Less important but intriguing: why on earth does Hibernate try to bind the four parameters "[Parent], [Adoptive], [Child2], [Parent]" to identify Child2 in the update query?

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations on `Parent.children` are the source of the problem.
Add `mappedBy`, remove `@JoinColumns` on the parent side.

The correct way to set this up:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

I believe the query generated for removal is the desired outcome.

```
Hibernate: delete from z_child where code=? and parent_code=? and parent_type=?
```

In addition, `removeChild` can be simplified - setting child's parent to null is not necessary - it will be handled anyway. This does not affect the query generated.

```
 public void removeChild(Child child){
    // child.setParent(null); No need to do that
    children.remove(child);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right! So do you think that the second question is also related to this? that is, Hibernate prepares four parameters because there are two @JoinColumns on each side?