# Hibernate One-To-Many cascade persist of child with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to achieve persisting a parent object with its children. The child object has a composite key which contains a foreign key to the parent.

The current mapping is unidirectional one to many and the parent owns the relationship.

Here is my model:

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Set<Child> children;

    ...
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ChildPK.class)
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @Id
    private String source;

    @Id
    private Long alternativeId;

    ...
```

PK:

```
class ChildPK implements Serializable {

    private Long parentId;
    private String source;
    private Long alternativeId;

    ...
```

Currently my issue is Hibernate is not handling populating the parentId in the Child, which I think is just me being hopeful it would, and I get constraint violation on the child. I am looking for ideas on how I can achieve building the parent object containing it's children and save it all in one go.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

I have asked a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413946/bidirectional-onetomany-relationship-with-composite-pks-using-springboot-and-hi). Take a look at the question and the answer (which worked).

In essence, you can try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(Child child){
       child.setParentId(this.id);
       children.add(child);
    }
    ...
```

and

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ChildPK.class)
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @Id
    private String source;

    @Id
    private Long alternativeId;

    ...
```

with the same ChildPk. Notice that on the Parent side we use `mappedBy` followed by the name of the Java property rather than `@JoinColumn` because the parent cannot be the owner of the association (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/whats-the-difference-between-joincolumn-and-mappedby-when-using-a-jpa-onetoma)). Also, it is useful to have an `addChild` method that correctly sets the properties on both sides of the relationship.

Success!